# Return dynamic type

Tags: d, variant, dynamic-typing, phobos

i know template like

```
T add(T)(T a, Tb){
    return  a + b;
}
```

But this need to user ask which type will be return, me i want compute inside method which type will be returned like:

```
T getField( size_t column ){
    if( column == 0 )
        T = int;
    else
        T = string;
    return to!T("1");
}
```

i do not know if i can cast to object and change prototype.

Thanks to all

Comment: What do you plan on doing with it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

D, like C, C++, C#, and Java is a statically typed language. *All* types must be known at compile time. So, no, you can't do what you're trying to do.

Now, you could use [inheritance](http://d-programming-language.org/class.html), [unions](http://d-programming-language.org/struct.html), or [std.variant.Variant](http://d-programming-language.org/phobos/std_variant.html) to get a form of dynamic typing, but not quite like what you're trying to do. That only works in dynamic languages.

- With classes, a class reference can point to an instance of a derived class rather than the base class that the reference is for, so you can get polymorphic/dynamic behavior, but the type of the base class is known at compile time, and anything that the reference refers to *must* be a derived type and therefore must be a class.
- With unions, you can have one variable which can hold different types using the same memory (so it can only be one type at a time), but it's generally considered a fairly low-level construct and best avoided if you don't really need it. A union does not keep track of what its current type is, so if it could be both an `int` and a `string`, it's quite easy for it to be holding an `int`, but you use it as a `string` (or vice versa), causing nasty bugs.
- With `Variant` (which is probably what you want to use), you can have one variable which can hold different types - similar to a union - but you don't specify which types that it can hold (unlike a union), and it actually keeps track of what type it currently holds (unlike a union), so it's much safer to use.

Comment: Great answer, but IMHO variant (especially the new one that's in the works) is basically an implementation of dynamic typing in D.

Comment: @dsimcha Yes, `Variant` is essentially trying to implement dynamic typing on top of static typing, but dynamic typing is not really supported by the language itself.